# How do I pass array as a key in JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

I have an API that expects `specialities[]` in the request body. The problem is that I don't know how to pass this as key in javascript.

This is what I'm doing:

```
const data = {
      name: name,
      phone: phone,
      email: registerEmail,
      pmc_number: pmcNumber,
      speciality[]: speciality.split(","),
      city: city 
    }

    const {res} = await axios.post("api-url", data);
```

But, `speciality[]` gives syntax error. So, is there any way I can send the data to the API (the API can't be changed. I have to find the solution from the client side). Thanks.

Comment: The key isn't supposed to be a type, it should be an identifier. The type can be whatever you assign it. `.split()` already creates an array, so just remove the `[]` from the key name. If the api requires you to include the `[]` in the key name then just quote the key so it's a string.

Comment: Put quotes around object keys that contain special characters.  `"speciality[]": value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put quotes around the key.

```js
'specialities[]': speciality.split(","),
```

Comment: close for clarity, it looks like the OP is confusing type annotations with property names.

Comment: Though if for some reason the API requires `specialties[]` as a key, then this answer seems appropriate. If the OP has any control over the API I would highly recommend removing `[]` from the key though.

Answer (score 1):

1. `'specialities': speciality.split(',')`
   describes the property using quotes and not a name, like in JSON.

   However, it is **not** **passing** a list/array.
2. An array is stringified: for example, `String([1,2])=='1,2';`. So `String([])==''`, and in a property, which is a string or symbol type,  does it make much of a a difference?